# document.on('load') is not firing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('load', function(){
    $("html").removeClass("wf-loading");
    $("body").css("opacity", 1);
    console.log('Load Triggered');
});
```

I have tried putting this code inside and outside `$(document).ready()` block but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Try changing 'document' to 'window', for shiggles

Answer (score 2):

The `load` event fires on the `window` object, not `document`.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    ...
})
```

It doesn't matter whether you put this inside `$(document).ready()`. The `window` object is created before running any Javascript.

Comment: ready happens after the load event?  the ready being once the dom has been created, and the load event happening after all resources (images and such) are loaded?  i feel like you got that backwards

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it is firing now. That was a silly mistake. I always thought `document` and `window` are interchangeable in these situations. :)

Comment: okay I rolled back my edit because I understand what you were trying to say about the ready, but it is confusing....

Comment: @epascarello Turns out I misread https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698214/1491895 so I was wrong about the order.